# Changing a PHP variable through a dropdown menu

Tags: php

I have a variable in PHP which controls the number of items that should be displayed from a database.

```
$per_page = 16;
```

And then I went on and paginated it because there were a few hundred items in the database. So cool, I have a 16 items being displayed per page and the user can click page 1 2 3 etc, you get the idea.

But now I'd like to chuck in a drop down box that allows the user to select the amount of items that are shown.

Originally I thought to do this using a drop down menu and I did this:

```
                echo 'Items per page';
            echo '<br>';
            echo '<select id="dropdown">';
            echo '<option value="1">20</option>';
            echo '<option value="2">40</option>';
            echo '<option value="3">All</option>';
            echo '</select>';
```

I then though if I could store that in a variable like $item_number I could then just change the $per_page to reflect the choice by maybe doing something like

```
$per_page = $item_number
```

But my problem is getting the drop down menu to tell $item_number how many to display so it can tell $per_page. Not too sure if I'm even going about this this right way but any help is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: AJAX is your friend in this case, jQuery makes it easy.

Comment: @apparatix Hmm, ok. Thanks. I've not played around with AJAX yet, guess I have some reading to do.

Answer (score 0):

you would need to either send the dropdown as a form, or AJAX to a PHP script that will either store the desired item_number in a session variable, or write to a database and read it from there.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding any guides online that deal with drop down menus that change the number of results displayed from a database. Do you know of any?

Comment: you can't be that specific. You'll need to learn how to use sessions, or learn how to use Ajax to post variables to a PHP script